# indexOf not working in IE 8/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, indexof

I am trying to run a jquery/ajax call that works in IE9, Chrome, FF, Opera
However, it fails in IE8 and UE7

The code:

```
  $.ajax({url:plink,
      success: function(result) {
        ppriser = result.split("**")[1];
        plabels = result.split("**")[2];
        pgrupper = result.split("**")[3];
        priser = ppriser.split("!#");
        labels = plabels.split("!#");
        grupper = pgrupper.split("!#");
        $("td .pricetag").each( function() {
          var slutpris = "999999";
          var slutlabel = "";
          for(i=1;i<priser.length;i++) {
            str = String($(this).attr('group')); 
            grp = String(grupper[i]);
            pos = grp.indexOf(str);
            if(grp==str || pos>=0) {
              j=parseInt(priser[i]);
              k=parseInt(slutpris);
              if(j!=0 && j<k) {
                slutpris = priser[i];
                slutlabel = labels[i];
              }
              if(slutlabel=="") { slutlabel = "fra:"; }
              if(slutpris!="999999") { 
                $(this).html(slutpris);
                $(this).prev('td').html(slutlabel);
              }
              if(slutpris=="999999") {
                $(this).css('display','none');
                $(this).closest('.pris').css('display','none');
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }});
```

I have tried various combos of:
cache:false,
type:"POST",
type:"GET",
data:"HTML",
dataType:"HTML",
timeout: 10000,

An example of the link plink:

```
Default.aspx?ID=148&fb=true&mode=-1&groupid=1210405@@SHOP5,1210103@@SHOP5,
```

The jquery link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The ajax script link is placed at the end of the page.

Comment: perhaps the url does not get properly encoded... `@` should be encoded to `%40`.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console on IE7/8?

Comment: What is content-type for response of the URL "Default.aspx?ID=148&fb=true&mode=-1&groupid=1210405@@SHOP5,1210103@@SHOP5," ?  If it is application/json then IE8/7 will not work as expected. It should  be text/plain.

Comment: the content type is HTML, I get no error messages... replacing @@ with %40%40 made no difference

Comment: Correction Console: SCRIPT438: Object does not support property or method 'indexOf'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to cast to string in several wasy (as IE 8/7 does not like indexOf on array objects) but to no avail. Thereafter, I found this solution.

```
  if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
      for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
      }
      return -1;
    }
  }
```

I test if indexOf is supported - and if not the function is created.

Comment: hm, I thought `grp` would be a string rather than an array... `Array.prototype.indexOf` support has been added in IE9.

Comment: grp should be a string... but I tried both String(var) and var.toString but with no luck. Implementing the above worked...

Comment: Both `String(var)` and `var.toString` should give you the string representation of an Array. I have no clue what you did wrong there...